# Ejercicio sencillo: Curso introductorio de Python

Tags: python, lista

tengo una dificultad para resolver un ejercicio de un curso introductorio que estoy tomando. Básicamente mi ejercicio consiste en:

**''Escribí una función que sume los elementos de una lista, otra que cuente los elementos de una lista y una última función que calcule la media de los elementos de una lista.''**

*Y yo por ahora lo que tengo hecho es:*

```
def contador(lista):
  contador = 0
  for i in lista:
    contador += 1
  return contador

def sumatoria(lista):
  sumatoria = 0
  for i in lista:
    sumatoria += i
  return sumatoria

def media(mi_lista):
  mi_sumatoria = []
  mi_sumatoria.append(sumatoria)
  mi_contador = []
  mi_contador.append(contador)
  mi_lista = mi_sumatoria/mi_contador
  return mi_lista
```

La plataforma me 'aprueba' las primeras dos fx pero me dice: **TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'list' and 'list'** para la fx de la media.

Se que esto es cuestión de segundos para la gran mayoría, y mas allá de poder 'resolverlo', quiero poder entender como es que lo tendría que afrontar.

Gracias

Comment: estás declarando la sumatoria y el contador como listas (debieran ser numéricos). ¿Qué esperas obtener que la división de dos listas? Sé como multiplicar vectores pero dividirlos... nada

Comment: Gracias ffflabs por tu rta., tenes razón. Estoy empezando y se me escapan muchas cosas todavía. Ya fue solucionado!

Answer (score 4):

```
def media(mi_lista):
    c = contador(mi_lista)
    return sumatoria(mi_lista) / c if c > 0 else 0
```

Esta sería la forma correcta de realizar el método, teniendo en cuenta los dos métodos que creaste inicialmente. En cuanto a la función de media que habías creado, recuerda que mi_sumatoria y mi_contador son listas, por tanto la división no es permitida (En el .chm correspondiente a la versión de python que tengas instalada, también puedes encontrar más información).
Otra forma podría ser:

```
def media(mi_lista):
    c = len(mi_lista)
    return sum(mi_lista) / c if c > 0 else 0
```

Pero no se tiene en cuenta los dos primeros métodos.

Comment: Gracias Firefly. Me corre la solución perfectamente, pero si me permites, tengo una pregunta más. Por qué SI tenes que definir contador, y NO sumatoria?

Comment: No es necesario definir contador en ese método, es para no llamar dos veces la misma función. Igual podrías ponerlo `sumatoria(mi_lista) / contador(mi_lista) if contador(mi_lista) > 0 else 0`. Además, si no se verifica que el contador sea mayor que 0, podría darte error si la lista está vacía.